# `withTimeout` with optional timeout behavior

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Suppose I'm writing a helper function which supports both the "normal" and "timeout" behavior for a specified block: if the `timeMillis` parameter is `null`, then run the block normally, and otherwise, run it from within a `withTimeout` call.

I've come up with this implementation which looks dubious to me:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> withOptionalTimeout(timeMillis: Long?, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): T {
    if (timeMillis == null) {
        return block(CoroutineScope(currentCoroutineContext()))
    }
    return withTimeout(timeMillis, block)
}
```

1. What is the correct way to implement this function?
2. What is the correct way to implement this function as `inline` one?

Comment: I suggest going the simple route and replacing `null` with `Long.MAX_VALUE`. It will give just about enough time to our Solar system to evaporate, so it seems pretty safe in that aspect :)

Comment: True, but then there would be no educational value at least  :)

Comment: What would you like to improve in the version you've got?

Comment: In his article https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952 Roman Elizarov warns against reusing the current context. So that's the part that worries me in my version.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a second question about the `inline` version.

Comment: In the article Roman actually notes they used to _recommend_ `async(coroutineScope)` as a way to maintain the coroutine hierarchy. It just didn't solve all the problems. I think your code does the right thing here, except that I still find it cleaner to just pass an "infinite" timeout.

Comment: Won't the infinite timeout introduce a needless overhead?

Comment: True, some overhead will be there in the form of the scheduled cancellation. Your solution avoids that, although there's some overhead to the non-timeout path as well, allocating the scope object.

Answer (score 0):

(: This is an interesting and educational value question indeed!

Ideally, I'd implement something like this:

```
private suspend inline fun <T> withOptionalTimeoutInternal(
timeMillis: Long?,
noinline block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): T = if (timeMillis == null || timeMillis <= 0L) {
    suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn { uCont ->
        val context = uCont.context
        val coroutine = ScopeCoroutine(context, uCont) // internal
        coroutine.startUndispatchedOrReturn(coroutine, block) // internal
    }
} else {
    withTimeout(timeMillis, block)
}
```

But for better or worse coroutine constructors are internal, so we can't use them. So I'd implement something like this:

```
private suspend inline fun <T> withOptionalTimeout(timeMillis: Long?, crossinline block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T?): T? =
if (timeMillis != null && timeMillis > 0) {
    withTimeout(timeMillis) { block() }
} else {
    coroutineScope { block() }
}
```

Or this:

```
private suspend inline fun <T> withOptionalTimeout(
timeMillis: Long?,
crossinline block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T?
): T? =
    coroutineScope {
        val mainScope = this
        launch {
            if (timeMillis != null && timeMillis > 0) {
                delay(timeMillis)
                mainScope.cancel(CancellationException("Timeout reached"))
            }
        }
        block()
    }
```